# Actively read 150 x 150 pixels from a camera preview

Tags: camera, preview, pixel

I have set up an Android camera application that allows me to preview the camera in a Frame Layout within my main Activity. What I would like to do (without using camera specific functionality; I want this to be completely independent of hardware.) is out line 150 X 150 pixels in the center of the preview either by showing a box around the pixels or blurring all of the pixels except the 150 x 150. Additionally, without taking a picture, I would like to read these pixels. Ultimately the effect I am going for is, as the camera is moved I display the change in the red, green, and blue color concentrations within the 150 x 150 area.  I know how to do the nested for loop and get the color from the pixel, but I would need to know how to get the offset for the height and weight to start reading the pixels from.
Thanks in advance for all of your help!
Mike

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    final public String TAG = "MyActivity";
    static private Camera mCamera = null;
    static public Camera getCamera() { return mCamera; }
    private static boolean mBPreviewingCamera = false;
    private PreviewSurface mPS;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        String lMTH = "onCreate ";
        Log.i(TAG, lMTH + "Start");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_color_temperature_estimator);
        if (isThereACamera()) {
            mPreviewCamera(true);
            TextView lTVTemp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TV_TEMP);
            lTVTemp.setText("Camera exists able to proceed");
            lTVTemp = null;
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No camera! Uunable to proceed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            TextView lTVTemp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TV_TEMP);
            lTVTemp.setText("No camera! Uunable to proceed");
            lTVTemp = null;
        }
    }

    public void mPreviewCamera(boolean pBPreviewingCamera) {
        String lMTH = "mPreviewCamera ";
        try {
            if (pBPreviewingCamera) {
                Log.i(TAG, lMTH + "Open Camera");
                mCamera = Camera.open();
                mPS = new PreviewSurface(this);
                FrameLayout lFVPreview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.FL_Preview);
                lFVPreview.addView(mPS);
                lFVPreview = null;

                mBPreviewingCamera = true;
                Button lBTNTemp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BTN_CLOSE);
                lBTNTemp.setText(R.string.BTN_CLOSE);
                lBTNTemp = null;
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, lMTH + "Open Camera");
                mCloseCamera();
                Button lBTNTemp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BTN_CLOSE);
                lBTNTemp.setText(R.string.BTN_OPEN);
                lBTNTemp = null;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i(TAG, lMTH + e.getMessage());
            mCloseCamera();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public void mCloseCamera() {
        String lMTH = "mCloseCamera ";
        Log.i(TAG, lMTH + "Turn Camera Off");
        if (mCamera != null) {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
            mCamera.release();
        }
        mCamera = null;
        mBPreviewingCamera = false;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        String lMTH = "onPause ";
        Log.i(TAG, lMTH + "Turn Camera Off");
        mPreviewCamera(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
        String lMTH = "onDestroy ";
        Log.i(TAG, lMTH + "Turn Camera Off");
        mPreviewCamera(false);
    }

    /** Check if this phone has a camera */
    private boolean isThereACamera() {
        if (getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)){
            // There is a camera
            return true;
        } else {
            // There isn't a camera
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void mBTN(View view) {
        mPreviewCamera(!mBPreviewingCamera);
    }
}




public class PreviewSurface extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback  {
    final static public String TAG = "PreviewSurface";
    private SurfaceHolder mSH;

    /**
     * @param context
     */
    public PreviewSurface(Context pContext) {
        super(pContext);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        String lMTH = "PreviewSurface(Context pContext) ";
        Log.i(TAG, lMTH + "Constructor");

        pContext = null;
        mSH = getHolder();
        mSH.addCallback(this);
        mSH.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

    }


    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.view.SurfaceHolder.Callback#surfaceChanged(android.view.SurfaceHolder, int, int, int)
     */
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
        String lMTH = "surfaceChanged ";
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i(TAG, lMTH + "arg1 = " + arg1 + " arg2 " + arg2 + " arg3 " + arg3);
        if (arg0.getSurface() != null) {
            // stop old preview if it exists
            try {
                Log.i(TAG, lMTH + "Stop Preview ");
                MyActivity.getCamera().stopPreview();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.i(TAG, lMTH + "Stoping preview exception " + e.getMessage());

            }

            // start new preview
            try {
                Log.i(TAG, lMTH + "Set Preview ");
                MyActivity.getCamera().setPreviewDisplay(arg0);
                Log.i(TAG, lMTH + "Start Preview ");
                MyActivity.getCamera().startPreview();

            } catch (Exception e){
                Log.i(TAG, lMTH + "Starting camera preview exception " + e.getMessage());
            }
          }

          // stop preview before making changes

    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.view.SurfaceHolder.Callback#surfaceCreated(android.view.SurfaceHolder)
     */
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
        String lMTH = "surfaceCreated ";
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            Log.i(TAG, lMTH + "Set Preview ");
            MyActivity.getCamera().setPreviewDisplay(arg0);
            Log.i(TAG, lMTH + "Start Preview ");
            MyActivity.getCamera().startPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i(TAG, lMTH + "Exception " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.view.SurfaceHolder.Callback#surfaceDestroyed(android.view.SurfaceHolder)
     */
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
        String lMTH = "surfaceDestroyed ";
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i(TAG, lMTH + "Activity will handle destroy");

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> "I would need to know how to get the offset for the height and weight
>   to start reading the pixels from"

An easy way to get the offset for your nested for-loop is walked through with descriptive variables:

```
int xWidth = 150; // The length you want to concentrate on
int yHeight = 150;
int xCenter = previewWidth/2;
int yCenter = previewHeight/2;
int xStart = xCenter - xWidth/2;
int xEnd = xCenter + xWidth/2;
int yStart = yCenter - yHeight/2;
int yEnd = yCenter + yHeight/2;

for(int y = yStart; y < yEnd; y++) {
    for(int x = xStart; x < xEnd; x++) {
        // read pixels
    }
}
```

The previewWidth and previewHeight can be easily gotten from surfaceChange():

```
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
    previewWidth = w;
    previewHeight = h;
    ...
}
```

The reason I use many variables here is so that you can clearly see how I walked through this problem.

Let me know how it goes.